# Is there a way to order mysql rows by the occurrence frequency?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Is there a method to order mysql rows by the occurrence frequency?

Comment: If you are referring to your `count` column, then it should be possible.. Though.. you have to be more specific.. some SQL.. schema.. or data would be great...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT n, count(*) as freq
FROM your_table
GROUP BY n
ORDER BY freq DESC;
```

a more specific example:

```
SELECT n, count(*) as freq
FROM (
  SELECT 1 as n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 as n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 as n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 as n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as n) as your_table
GROUP BY n
ORDER BY freq DESC;
```

will return:

```
n, freq
3, 3
2, 2
1, 1
```